# Change AppBarLayout height programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, appbar

I'm trying to implement Flexible Space with image pattern, using [this tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/).

Everything works fine.

Notice the height definition of the AppBarLayout which is 192dp.

I'd like to make the height 1/3 of the screen instead, to match [this google example for the pattern here](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQscXNQY3dNdVlYeTQ/patterns-scrolling-techniques_flex_space_image_xhdpi_003.webm).

Here's the code in the activity's onCreate (the layout xml is exactly the same as in the tutorial):

```
AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appbar);
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float heightDp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / density;
appbar.setLayoutParams(new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Math.round(heightDp / 3)));
```

But for some reason, the result is not what I'm expecting. I can't see the app bar at all with this code. (without the code, the height shows as expected but it's from XML and can't be set dynamically).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
    AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    float heightDp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 3;
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appbar.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = (int)heightDp;
```

In your original code I think that you calculation for 1/3 of the screen was wrong, but you still should have seen something.  It could be that the LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT in the setLP() wasn't imported correctly.  Always declare the view type first, i.e. CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams just to make sure.  Otherwise it can be easy to use a Framelayout.LayoutParams, for instance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this?: float density = mParentActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            float heightDp = mParentActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / density;

Answer (score 3):

Some methods for changing the AppBarLayout height programatically with dividing, percent or by weight of the screen height:

```
private AppBarLayout appbar;

/**
 * @return AppBarLayout
 */
@Nullable
protected AppBarLayout getAppBar() {
    if (appbar == null) appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    return appbar;
}

/**
 * @param divide Set AppBar height to screen height divided by 2->5
 */
protected void setAppBarLayoutHeightOfScreenDivide(@IntRange(from = 2, to = 5) int divide) {
    setAppBarLayoutHeightOfScreenPercent(100 / divide);
}

/**
 * @param percent Set AppBar height to 20->50% of screen height
 */
protected void setAppBarLayoutHeightOfScreenPercent(@IntRange(from = 20, to = 50) int percent) {
    setAppBarLayoutHeightOfScreenWeight(percent / 100F);
}

/**
 * @param weight Set AppBar height to 0.2->0.5 weight of screen height
 */
protected void setAppBarLayoutHeightOfScreenWeight(@FloatRange(from = 0.2F, to = 0.5F) float weight) {
    if (getAppBar() != null) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getAppBar().getLayoutParams();
        params.height = Math.round(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * weight);
        getAppBar().setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

If you want to follow the material design guidelines the height should be equal to the default height plus content increment(s)
https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar